# Are the return values vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices consistent between different VkInstances?

Tags: c++, vulkan

Situation:

I have a function that determines whether or not there is a Vulkan-supported device and returns that device if one is found. If no such device is found, it will return a null value and a legacy code path will be used.

The issue is that, because this function needs to be called *before* the application uses the Vulkan code path, it has to create it's own temporary `VkInstance`. The function calls `vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices` to get the `VkPhysicalDevice`s, and uses `vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties` to determine whether or not there is a suitable device.

The `VkPhysicalDevice` itself cannot be returned since it's tied to the `VkInstance` (which is temporary and will be destroyed before the function returns), so instead the function returns the index of the device in the array under the assumption that `vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices`will return the same array when called a second time on a different `VkInstance`.

Question:

Is `vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices` guaranteed to return the same values when called using two different `VkInstances`? This is assuming the same machine and same instance of the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification provides no such guarantee. So your idea isn't guaranteed to work at all.

It would be better for you to keep the `VkInstance` around, rather than creating one solely for the purposes of device enumeration. So instead of just storing an index, you store the `VkPhysicalDevice` and the instance. If they're null, then Vulkan isn't available.

Attempting to use the `pipelineCacheUUID` won't work either, as the specification does not require it to uniquely identify a device:

> used to identify a compatible device and driver combination to use when serializing and de-serializing pipeline state.

There's no guarantee that it won't change between instances. However, if you have access to the extensions VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2 and VK_KHX_external_memory_capabilities, then you can query the `VkPhysicalDeviceIDPropertiesKHX` from a device. That includes a `deviceUUID` which is explicitly required to uniquely identify a particular device, "across API and driver boundaries".

Comment: Alternatively he could store `pipelineCacheUUID` to id particular device without keeping instance alive.

Comment: Actually, there is such guarantee for the **same** `VkInstance`: "2.4.1. Lifetime of Retrieved Results".

Comment: @krOoze: Actually, `pipelineCacheUUID` won't work. I've added an explanation of why not.

Comment: Interesting. That is actually in contradiction of what the spec says: "`pipelineCacheUUID` is an array of size `VK_UUID_SIZE`, containing 8-bit values that represent a **universally unique identifier** for **the device**." Funny thing is they even say so in the Issue you quote: "despite its description in the specification". :)

Comment: Additionally I would argue that one could want to actually identify device-driver combination, not the actual raw device for the purpose in the Q.